# 1-form $\theta=y_{1}dx^1+y_2dx^2$ conjugate momenta

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, change-of-basis

I'm considering on cotangent bundle of a two-dimensional variety where in canonical coordinates $(x^i,y_i)$ is defined in the 1-form 
$$\theta=y_{1}dx^1+y_2dx^2$$
let new coordinate:
$$x^1=q^1\cosh(q^2)$$
$$x^2=q^1\sinh(q^2)$$
I have to determinate:

1) the conjugate momenta $(p_{\alpha})$ concerning to $(q^{\alpha})$

2) the components of $\theta(q^{\alpha},p_{\alpha})$.

I think I can replace:

$$dx^1=\cosh(q^2)dq^1+q^1\sinh(q^2)dq^2$$
$$dx^2=\sinh(q^2)dq^1+q^1\cosh(q^2)dq^2$$

Unfortunately I know the definition of conjugate momenta  only in Hamiltonian mechanics $p_{\mu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial u^{\mu}}$ and I do not know how  to go on here. 
 I looked for a definition but I did not find it.

Comment: The canonical 1-form is $p\,dq$ in any coordinate system...

Answer (score 2):

In Hamiltonian mechanics, the conjugate momenta are the cotangent vectors. When the tautological one-form $\theta$ is written as $$\theta=\sum_i y_idx_i$$ in canonical coordinates $(x^i,y_i)$, the canonical momenta are precisely $y_i$.

You may refer to equation $(4)$ of the following answer on a physics stackexchange post to see how conjugate momenta transforms between coordinates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176555/momentum-is-a-cotangent-vector/176578#176578 . Remember that there is a hidden summation over all $i$ on the right-hand-side of that equation.

The $q^i$ in that answer corresponds to $x^i$ in your question; the $p_i$ in that answer corresponds to $y_i$ in your question; the $q'^j$ in that answer corresponds to $q^j$ in your question; the $p_j'$ in that question corresponds to $p_j$ in your question.